# I'm trying to make a shooting game with love2d but it can't shoot

Tags: lua, love2d

the table is always empty when i press space.but it works if I use love.keypressed(key).I see in the tutorials,it should work if using love.keyborad.isDown the insert bullets into bullet table.

```
--bullet.lua
Bullet=Object:extend()
function Bullet:new()
    self.image=love.graphics.newImage("sprite/bullet.png")
    self.x=player.x
    self.y=player.y
    self.spd=800
    bullets={}

end
function Bullet:draw()
    if facingL then
        love.graphics.draw(self.image,self.x+20,self.y+20)
    elseif not facingL then
        love.graphics.draw(self.image,self.x,self.y+20)
    end
    
end
function Bullet:update(dt)
    local vx=0
    if love.keyboard.isDown("space") then
        table.insert(bullets,Bullet(self.x,self.y))
        print(#bullets)
    end

    if facingL then
        vx=self.spd*-1
    else
        vx=self.spd
    end
    
    self.x=self.x+vx*dt
end
-- main.lua
function love.update(dt)
 for i,v in ipairs(bullets) do
    v:update(dt)
  end
function love.draw()
  for i,v in ipairs(bullets) do
    v:draw()
  end
```

Comment: The program checks the space key when it updates a bullet. If there are no bullets then it doesn't update any bullets so it never checks the space key. Right?

Comment: (If this confuses you I suggest re-studying basic programming, like the order in which the computer does the commands.)

Comment: So, in order to fix, move the shooting part into the correct function

Answer (score 0):

try putting `if love.keyboard.isdown("space") then` in the `love.update(dt)` function.
like this:

```
function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("space") then
        table.insert(bullets,Bullet(self.x,self.y))
        print(#bullets)
    end
    -- other stuff
end
```

hopefully this helps!